# Show dates from Db in google chart

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I wanted to show the month for a specific date in my google chart I have this JSON(livedata.php) code:

> ```
> $data_points = array();
> while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
> $monthNum = date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));
> $DayNum = date('d', strtotime($row['time_stamp']));     
> $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
> $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
> if($monthNum == "7"){
>       if (array_key_exists($DayNum, $data_points)) {
>       $data_points[$DayNum]->ph += $row['ph'];
>       $data_points[$DayNum]->moist += $row['moist'];
>           }else{
>         $data_points[$DayNum]->ts = $DayNum;
>       $data_points[$DayNum]->ph = $row['ph'];
>       $data_points[$DayNum]->moist = $row['moist'];   
>   }
> } }
> echo json_encode(array_values($data_points));
> ```

That Shows the following Output:

> [{"ts":"29","ph":"8","moist":"2"},{"ts":"28","ph":40,"moist":35},{"ts":"27","ph":16,"moist":8}]

the output above means: the ph value on a specific date from the month of July.I wanted to show ts: Month day but my chart shows nothing

Now to output a graph I have this kind of javascript code and chart:

> ```
> google.charts.load('current', {
>     callback: drawChart,
>     packages: ['corechart']
>     });
>
>  function drawChart() {
>      var jsonData = $.ajax({
>      url: 'livedata.php',
>      dataType: 'json',}).done(function (results) {
>
>      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>
>      data.addColumn('date', 'time_stamp');
>      data.addColumn('number', 'ph');
>      data.addColumn('number', 'moist');
>
>
>      $.each(results, function (i, row) {
>      var dbdate = new Date();
>
>      data.addRow([
>      new Date(dbdate.getFullYear(), dbdate.getMonth(), row.ts),
>      parseFloat(row.ph),
>      parseFloat(row.moist)]);});
>
>      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
>
>      chart.draw(data, {
>      title: 'Soil Analysis'});});
> }
> ```

having an output below:
[image]

I am wondering why it happened to be september.I guess it is all because of the date() from my javascript.What should i need to do?Please Help!!I am really a newbie in terms of chart and web visualization.I am asking for Help.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about what I found, but your dbdate initialization might be causing it: the constructor `Date()` called without any argument creates a Date with the current time in your system. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) out